# MVC3 Razor: how to check if model is empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have tried using !Model.Any() it doesn't work, since model has no extension Any. How to solve?
Here is my code snippet.

```
    @model MyModel.Work
    @if ( !Model.Any() )
    {
       <script type="text/javascript">
             alert("Model empty");
       </script>
    }
    else
    {
       <script type="text/javascript">
              alert("Model exists");
       </script>
    }
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It sounds to me like you are instantiating the model, but want to check and see if it's been populated.

My standard way of doing this is to create a `bool` property called `Empty`, only giving a get, and then return the check you need to see if no other properties have been set.

Say you have a Customer class as your model:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId {get;set;}
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public string Email {get;set;}

    public bool Empty
    {
        get { return (CustomerId == 0 && 
                      string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FirstName) &&
                      string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LastName) &&
                      string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Email));         
            }
    }
}
```

Now in your model, you simply call:

```
@model MyModel.Work
@if (Model.Empty)
{
   <script type="text/javascript">
         alert("Model empty");
   </script>
}
else
{
   <script type="text/javascript">
          alert("Model exists");
   </script>
}
```

Comment: first script line gives "Expected ';'" warning.

Comment: is it also possible to tell user which property is empty ?

Answer (score 22):

You can try this:

```
@if (Model.Count == 0)
{

}
```

Comment: @if (Model.Count() == 0) it's missing () after Count

Comment: I would say this is a better method. (Of course, it should be `Model.Count()`. Testing for null does not work.

Answer (score 11):

how about this:

```
if(Model == null)
{
}
```

Comment: then your model is not empty. Debug it, see why is it not empty.

Comment: Empty != null. An empty collection is still a collection.

Comment: `@if (Model == null)` wont work, because Model always return with some other associate values.

Answer (score 6):

`@if(!Model.Any()){}` works when you are passing a list of data as your model. If you are trying to check if model is empty which is not a list and may contain single record or none then I normally use `@if(Model == null)`.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 3):

A combination of info from the previous answers worked for me.

```
@if (Model != null && Model.Count() != 0)
{
   <ul>
       <li><strong>Hello World</strong></li>
   </ul>
}
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I don't know if it matters, but i use MVC5. I forgot to send anything from controller to the view. Since i put "return View(myList);"
in my controller, method .Any() works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
    `
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    
    namespace APIPractice.Models.EmployeeModel
    {
        public class LoginModel
        {
            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }
    
            [Required]
            public string Username { get; set; }
    
            [Required]
            public string Password { get; set; }
    
            [Required]
            public string RePassword { get; set; }
    
            [Required]
            public int IsActive { get; set; }
    
            public bool Empty
            {
                get
                {
                    if (
                            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Username) ||
                            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Password) ||
                            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RePassword) ||
                            IsActive == 0
                          )
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return true;
                    };
                }
            }
    
        }
    }`
    
and in your controller

    `if (loginModel.Empty)
    { 
        //your success code.
    }else{
        //Your fail msg.
    }`
```